# How to disable Material UI DataGrid go to next page button while loading the API

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

This code is regarding Material UI Datagrid
I need to disable the Go to next page button while loading the API

```
    <DataGrid
      autoHeight
      getRowHeight={getRowHeight}
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      page={page - 1}
      rowCount={total}
      rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPage}
      pagination
      paginationMode='server'
      pageSize={pageSize}
      getRowClassName={(params) => getRowClassName(params)}
      onPageChange={(newPage) => handelPageChange(newPage)}
      loading={isLoading}
      // disableNextPage={isLoading}
      onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) =>
        setAssetList((prveState) => ({
          ...prveState,
          pageSize: newPageSize,
        }))
      }
    />
```

Comment: Is that okay if you disable the pagination component instead pagination item (next button)?

Comment: yeah @RashedRahat

Answer (score 6):

I have used this prop it has been resolved

hideFooterPagination={isLoading}

Comment: hideFooter is just enough